Plotting arrows whose lengths are proportional to a list of numbers on a 2D grid
I am trying to plot arrows whose lengths are proportional to a list of numbers, on top of a 2D arrayplot. For example, I have an Arrayplot like this-

I was able to lay circles whose diameter was proportional to the "color" of the array plot. For example, the largest diameter circle is overlaid on the darkest square, the circle with zero radius on the lightest square, so on and so forth. Something like this-

Instead of the circles, I want to have arrows/line segments whose length is proportional to the color. I am not sure how to do that. Any hints will be greatly appreciated

Please post the code to generate the Arrayplot, so people can copy and paste it

As a possible display combination use a 10x10 color array and a graphics primitives array of arrows with centered start point as an Epilog
     lattice =  { (*  array orgin (1/2,1/2), color  r, g, random blue*)
              Array[(RGBColor[0.3 + #1/10, 0.3 + #2/10, 
                                RandomReal[{0, 0.6}]] &), {10, 10}, 1/2],
   {(* array origin (1/2,1/2), arrow from center (n,m)  to (n,m - quadratic)   *)
    Thickness[0.005],
    Array[( 
        Arrow[ N[{{#1, #2}, {#1, #2 - #1^2/20} + 
                4/Sqrt[1 + #1^2 + #2^2] {1, 1}}]]   &), 
    {10, 10},  {1/2,   1/2}]}}  ;


